# Powershell execute an action on compliance search

Tags: powershell

I created a new compliance search, and started the compliance search, now i want to execute an action with that compliance search to purge the results. However, i keep getting that the flag -Purge is not available.

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-ComplianceSearchAction -Purge -PurgeType SoftDelete -SearchName "TEST delete a meeting"
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Purge'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ComplianceSearchAction], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-ComplianceSearchAction
    + PSComputerName        : nam05b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com
```

I have also tried re-ordering the flags as checked below, still the same error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "TEST delete a meeting" -Purge -PurgeType "SoftDelete"
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Purge'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ComplianceSearchAction], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-ComplianceSearchAction
    + PSComputerName        : nam05b.ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but Ill answer it in case it helps anyone else who comes by it...

The error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name..." can be misleading.  If your syntax is correct(and yours is) it usually means that you don't have sufficient permission to run the action for that commandlet.  According to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/new-compliancesearchaction-purge-parameter-cant-be/d06af683-29e0-4a50-8905-0452219a2e79) question on answers.microsoft:

> To delete messages, a person has to be a member of the Organization
>   Management role group or be assigned the Search And Purge management
>   role.

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-for-and-delete-messages-in-your-organization)

You may be wondering "why doesn't it just tell me that I don't have permission?"  It makes a little more sense when you understand why you get this error.  Remember that your session can't see(for lack of a better term) parameters or commandlets you don't have permissions for.  So depending on what you are trying to do PowerShell may tell you "thats not a valid command" or "thats not a valid parameter", when in fact those *are* valid commmands and parameters, your session just can't *see* them if you don't have access to run it.  This will also happen if you are connected to a wrong URI in your O365 PowerShell session(e.g. the outlook uri instead of the compliance uri)